# How do I create a dynamically named global variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables, node-red

In Node-RED I am trying to create a global variable from a part of an MQTT topic:

```
var mytopic = msg.topic;
shortcode = mytopic.replace(/.*presence\/(.*)/, '$1');
global.set(shortcode, '1');
```

The documentation mentions `global.set('foo', 'bar');` but how do I set the variable name, *foo*, dynamically?

Comment: Dynamically created global variable sounds like not the best (terrible?) design decision. If you explain the problem the community may have helped you to solve it in a better way.

Comment: Just basing this off of the syntax, but if the set method takes in two strings, or a string and some other value, then there shouldn't be any reason you couldn't pass a variable as the first parameter,  The called really doesn't know if the caller gave it a static string or a variable.

Comment: You've not said why you think what you have doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the replies.

As suggested it should actually work and it does. My error lay elsewhere. I am aware of the risks of using global variables. Now I can work with MQTT topics like '+/presence/#' (containing information about the presence of different items detected by several sensors) with *one* flow.